# Input type "number" not working as expected in Microsoft Edge

Tags: html, browser, microsoft-edge

I have an `input` field as follows

```
<input class="calc-parameter" type="number" placeholder="" 
data-parameter-name="NUMERIC" maxlength="12" id="NUMERIC-2-0">
```

On all browsers, I am getting the spinner and/or the keyboard is only allowing numbers to be entered

On Microsoft Edge, the user can enter numbers or characters into the field. Is there another property I need to add for Edge to consider this a numeric field only? Or is this a known Edge bug? I could not find anything on the Microsoft forums

Comment: As of my knowledge microsoft edge is quite fresh to web development, alot of function that firefox, chrome etc support are not included in microsoft edge

Comment: the jquery forms plugin provides a polyfill

Comment: I'm looking at [jquery forms plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#getting-started), where can I find polyfill  there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They claim its supported:
https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number
but does not include the spinner feature.

However there is a bug filed in that the functionality doesn't work:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/10792541/

Ran into this one myself.

Comment: It's not being fixed. Good thing Edge is switching to Chromium.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late to the party but if someone is still looking for a workaround in Jquery whilst Edge catches up with google:

```
$('input[type=number]').on('keypress', function (e) {
// Add whatever keys you want to the condition (48-57 = numbers)
    if (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57) { 
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```